# How to Fill background cell in excel using python?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have an excel file can't able to fill background colour of a cell.Below is the code

```
 import openpyxl
 import pdb
 from openpyxl import Workbook
 from openpyxl.styles import Color, PatternFill, Font, Border
 from openpyxl.styles import colors
 from openpyxl.cell import Cell
 wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('fancy.xlsx')
 ws = wb.active
 fill = PatternFill(fill_type=None,start_color='FFFFFFFF',end_color='FF000000')
 ws['A2'].fill = fill
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: We can't help if we don't know what's wrong...

Comment: What seems to be the problem with the code?

Comment: excel file is same as it is not change no color in A2 column

Comment: Did you ever saved the file afterwards? with `wb.save()`. If you don't save you won't see any changes...

Comment: yes done at once

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: yes done but no change

Comment: You are setting the fill wrongly; set fill_type="solid" and it'll work fine.